# How to pass HTTP response to JSON?

Tags: symfony5

I am working on a code base where controller have following lines of codes. The controller checks for exception and return JSON response if no error, otherwise throw exception error.

```
     return $this->exception->tryCatch(
        fn () => $this->json(
            $this->customer->addUser()
        )
    );

public function tryCatch(callable $work): Response
{
    try {
        return $work();
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

But this always results 200 response. If I need different response(201), how can I adjust this code. I have been asked not to break the code structure. So asking here for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /**
 * Returns a JsonResponse that uses the serializer component if enabled, or json_encode.
 */
protected function json($data, int $status = 200, array $headers = [], array $context = []): JsonResponse
```

The second argument to the `json` method takes the status of the response. By default it is 200, you can specify your own.

For example:

```
 $this->json($this->customer->addUser(), 201);
```